# Android new Intent memory leak / out of memory

Tags: android, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, android-memory

I've got an app with 2 Activities. The first one launches on startup and with a button launches the second activity using an Intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.example.project.SomeActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

In the second activity I have a camera and some memory allocation.

When I press the 'close' button in the second activity, I call Close on the camera and finish on the activity.

```
    m_camera.Close(CameraEnum.FRONT.getCameraID());
    this.finish();
    System.gc();
```

When I close the activity for the first time and call it back from the first activity all is good, also for the second time - but when I open it in the third time - I get an out of memory error on this line:

```
m_data = new byte[4*width*height];
```

The error I get is:

```
05-19 14:22:51.440: E/dalvikvm-heap(31838): Out of memory on a 1228816-byte allocation.
...
05-19 14:42:42.174: E/AndroidRuntime(7345): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

I can find out why this should happen.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: m_data = new byte[4*width*height]; that`s could be a lot of memory. Are you managing large bitmap?

Comment: it is a memory for a bitmap. But why would it crush only on the third run?

Comment: you have probably a memory leak. For some reason a reference is held and can not be GC collected. Without see the code is impossible to look for where the error is

Comment: If I call this.finish() on the activity - won't it clean all memory?

Comment: It will finish the Activity. But if a reference is held, the Activity is not freed from the memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, found the problem - it really was a memory leak due to holding a reference to the 'Context' object.
After releasing it - the app doesn't crash anymore.

Comment: I seem to be getting this same error. how did you release it?